# How do I Add or change error bars in coefplot2?

Tags: errorbar, coefplot, glmm

I am plotting graphs for my glmm models in R and I would like the coefplot2 to have a different error bar. Is it possible? Currently I have this graph:
[image]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]

Can I change the error bars to match this way? I don't understand how to add them from my model. Cannot find any help on coefplot2 package that speaks of this. What command can I use?

This is my code for the graph:

```
coefplot2(mod, vertical=FALSE,
          col = 1, lty = 2, pch=15,var.las=1, varnames=c("NE","NW","S","SE","SW","W"),
          ylab="Log Odd Ratios", xlab="Aspect", mar=c(5,5,5,2), frame.plot=TRUE )
```

I would appreciate the help